# Regex validation phone number with brackets optional characters not working

Tags: regex, kotlin

I am working on a validation with Regex and the condition is below

```
+1(061)235-663 - valid
1(061)235-663 - valid
(061)235-663 - valid
```

The regex I am trying is below

```
val regex = """\d{3}([-.])\d{3}\1\d{4}|\d{10}|^(\+1|1)?(\(\d{3}\)\d{3}\-\d{3})$""".toRegex()
```

our focus is on last part : `^(\+1|1)?(\(\d{3}\)\d{3}\-\d{3})`

I am not able to escape +1. other cases are working. So the scenario is like that, 1 and +1 is optional.

It seems like back slash not working as escape character in kotlin Regex

Comment: `^(?:\+?1)?\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{3}$` probably? But your own attempt should be working too right.

Comment: `+` is escaped well. Did you mean you want the whole string to match? Add `$` at the end, `^(\+1|1)?\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{3}$` ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PtkGLr/1))

Comment: The regex already matches the given examples

Comment: @evolutionxbox
 `+1(061)235-663` -- -this not matching that is why I have posted as question someone please have a look

Comment: @Santhucool yes it does? https://regex101.com/r/yi5MPj/1

Comment: Please also note that there is a difference between JavaScript and Java. Where are you trying to use the regex and how?

Comment: @evolutionxbox
  using kotlin I have some other conditions as well . please have a look     `val regex = """\d{3}([-.])\d{3}\1\d{4}|\d{10}|^(\+1|1)?\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{3}$""".toRegex()
`. The last or condition is we talks about `^(\+1|1)?\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{3}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[+|(|\d]?[\d|(|\s|]+[)|\s]+\d+[-|\s]+\d+
```

logic used is

1. starting with + or "(" or a digit
2. second char is "(" or space or digit. it can be of any length, if you need 3 u can limit
3. next stop is either at ")" or space
4. then followed by numbers of any length
5. then followed by "-" or space
6. then followed by digits.

these can be used just as direction to what finally you need.
https://regex101.com/r/GKlnoz/1

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you need to catch, but if you add a second group, you will only match the number `(061)235-663`

```
^(\+1|1)?(\(\d{3}\)\d{3}\-\d{3})
```

[see Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lEo33c/1)